# Securely erase Intel SSD using Live Boot CD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd

So I am selling on a computer and wish to securely erase the HDD. I've booted into a Live CD (Ubuntu) and run the following commands:

`sudo hdparm --security-set-pass NULL /dev/sda`

and

`sudo hdparm --security-erase-enhanced NULL /dev/sda`

It appears to have run successfully but it only took about a minute and half, how do I know it has run properly?

EDIT:

I went into GPARTED and had to create a partition table which I've never had to do before, I assume that means it worked?

Comment: Please give the results: `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda `

Answer (score 0):

Try badblocks

badblocks -svwf /dev/sda should sovle your problem.

-w means that in every block of your hard drive badblocks will write random pattern (ex. 0x55) of course pattern in every cycle is different.

Wait until badblocks will finish full 5 cycles of writing/reading.